# Rename file in bare Git repository

Tags: git

I have one central bare git repository and many developers adding some new files to it.
I would like to sequentially name these files (a some kind of changelog), but due to review process (introduced some delays), it is hard to choose the correct next change number manually - probability of duplicates is high.

It would be very nice to have some hook (post-commit is enough) in central repository, which will just rename newly added file according to the rules. Making git clone on the server's side looks a bit complicated and error prone.

Are there any low-level git commands to achieve my goal? 
Thanks.

Comment: You want to rename files after they've then pushed? This sounds like an ill-fated idea... That means your local developer repos will have discrepant names. Could get confusing fast.

Comment: I agree to make it as additional commit. Local developer cannot choose proper name at the time of local commit+push. Review is done with Gerrit tool, so pushed commit is eventually merged to the main branch.

Comment: I would still argue it's a bad idea. You're basically invalidating local repository filenames the moment a developer pushes code for review. This means work in progress has to navigate rename merges and the workflow fails the hallway test: Dev A -- "Hey did you see the changes I pushed to `fileA`." Dev B -- "No I just pulled though. Wait, do you mean `fileBravo`?" That written you could probably do it in post-receive.

Comment: I want files be renamed only if they have passed the review. These files are database changes, which should be applied one by one in the strict order. So Dev committed "ticket111.sql", it passed the review, merged to master and then renamed to some '0102.sql' This sequential names are used by tool to automate db updates. All references to the actual file name can be done via bugtracking software, which has links to the commits - "Look, I have done it for ticket 111".

Comment: So this is sort of a difficult problem in hooks, after trying a few experiments. Bare repos don't have working trees. Non-bare repos won't let you change the HEAD of a checked-out branch. Might be a way to launch a script that executes the change in a *third* repository but I also can't make it work. Might be my problem, however, and not git's. Is it sufficient for your reviewers to fire off a script manually, say, once or twice a day? The operation itself is very easy to script outside of a hook.